# Hide GenerateBlocks Pro link from Wordpress sidebar (back-end) for a specific user role

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, wordpress-plugin-creation

I'm trying to hide the GenerateBlocks Pro link from the WordPress sidebar with the following code but for some reason, it doesn't work

```
if ( !current_user_can( 'moderate_comments' ) )
    add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_admin_menu_links' );
function remove_admin_menu_links(){
    remove_menu_page( 'edit-comments.php' ); // Comments
    remove_menu_page( 'tools.php' ); // Tools
    remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=gblocks_templates' ); // GenerateBlocks
}
```

Comment: How is this question different from [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66930036/remove-my-sites-sub-menu-for-the-a-specific-user-role-in-wordpress-multisite) you posted an hour ago, which is still open?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution:

```
    remove_menu_page( 'generateblocks' );
```

Credits & Thanks go to @tom-usborne